# User validations email uniqueness Rspec FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot

i have been even trying pending on this but it still gives error.

Userfactory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence :email do |n|
        "email#{n}@evercam.io"
    end
  factory :user, class: :EvercamUser do
    sequence(:firstname) { |n| "firstname#{n}" }
    sequence(:lastname) { |n| "lastname#{n}" }
    sequence(:username) { |n| "username#{n}" }
    sequence(:password) { |n| "password#{n}" }
    email
    sequence(:api_id) {|n| SecureRandom.hex(10)}
    sequence(:api_key) {|n| SecureRandom.hex(16)}
    # is_admin false
    country do
        country = Country.where(iso3166_a2: 'ie').first
        country || create(:ireland)
    end
  end
end
```

UserSpec

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe 'validations' do
    it { should validate_presence_of :email }
    it { should validate_presence_of :firstname }
    it { should validate_presence_of :lastname }
    it { should validate_presence_of :username }
    it { should validate_presence_of :encrypted_password }
    describe 'email uniqueness' do
      before { create :user, email: 'foo@bar.com' }
      let(:user) { build :user, email: 'foo@bar.com' }
      it do
        user.valid?
        expect(user.errors[:email]).to be == ['has already been taken']
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'associations' do
    it { should belong_to(:country) }
    # it { should have_many(:camera_shares) }
  end

  it 'has a valid factory' do
    expect(build(:user)).to be_valid
  end
end
```

and here is my UserModel which is `Devise`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :country

  validates :firstname, presence: true
  validates :lastname, presence: true
  validates :username, presence: true
  validates :encrypted_password, presence: true

  def fullname
    "#{firstname} #{lastname}"
  end

  def self.created_months_ago(number)
    given_date = number.months.ago
    User.where(created_at: given_date.beginning_of_month..given_date.end_of_month)
  end
end
```

I have even tried to give "`pending`" to all blocks but it still giving me error i dont know where i am wrong on this

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: At which point in your spec you get the error?

Comment: can't you use the validate_uniqueness_of helper provided by shoulda matchers? http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/Shoulda%2FMatchers%2FActiveRecord%3Avalidate_uniqueness_of

Comment: tried and same error

Comment: Would be helpful if you could elaborate on the "error". i.e. is this validation error, or is this an error exception being raised when ran in rspec? if this is a validation error, please show the full error message. If this is an exception, please show the backtrace error message with the relevant lines of codes of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it { should validate_presence_of :email }
```

If it fails on the line above, it is because the model does not in fact have a validation for `:email`:

```
validates :firstname, presence: true
validates :lastname, presence: true
validates :username, presence: true
validates :encrypted_password, presence: true
# validates :email, presence: true # <---- missing in action
```